# Keycloak REST Api can't create new user

Tags: python-3.x, keycloak

```
def create_client(token):

    url ='http://localhost:8080/admin/realms/IDMAR_REALM/users'

    headers = {
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization' : f"Bearer {token}",
        'Accept': 'application/json'
        }

    data = {
        "firstName":"nome",
        "lastName":"cognome",
        "email":"aaa@aaa.it",
        "enabled":"true",
        "username":"user"
    }
    x = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data, verify=False)
    print ('#2 CREATE USER ',x, x.content, x.text)




def requ_token(): 
    
    user = 'admin'
    passwd = 'admin'
    payload = {
        "username": user, 
        "password": passwd,
        "grant_type": "password",
        "client_id": 'admin-cli',
        "client_secret": 'MLzVqLENPhOQlOChZVbGb9EbpJPtgVLF'
    }
    #payload = {
    #    "grant_type": "client_credentials",
    #    "client_id": 'admin-cli',
    #    "client_secret": 'MLzVqLENPhOQlOChZVbGb9EbpJPtgVLF'
    #}

    r = requests.post('http://0.0.0.0:8080/realms/IDMAR_REALM/protocol/openid-connect/token', data=payload, verify=False).json()
    print('#1', r)
    create_client(r.get('access_token'))

requ_token()
```

i receive correctly the token, the output of #1 print is:

```
{'access_token': 'eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJaY090S1phaFhjQnpfdmFkWWlCdkt6OHBvWVBtWVpRUDM4V0xpLUlFbk1rIn0.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.aM2UGb1BWPvIQdR_2GEtiDTSK3JHwtxVydqL79xluAdWjlwmlAfP-YESvGxw06U04Dh7FKmywkdDLHyoOh-7FDk6bfaAGLEx6CWtI7JeEIY2b6lO5p5nHvxmIBKwcqQ-_GsPbVU6j8hSvVmO0p8jEgNuTxJ-PzTDHtm_x9M4kz9xNAoz52JwMU01CyEohjPgI54Y0kS1nnHM-e8RD5oyzTE45LeOnx2pySU0Rzi6OVwB7Rnb0piCLqq-iKFKIf5mId4plwXgCFWaMor5zNa19JLL1GCaDyHkQP5RRzEiSPDlTNzRspVkzKjFyyn-A_Zs7wmhAW9TCADu9fc_Ck2m6g', 'expires_in': 300, 'refresh_expires_in': 1800, 'refresh_token': 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICI1YzY4N2NmOS1kNzg2LTQ3YTEtODNkNi1iMTE4YTJmYWNmOTAifQ.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.BF7XR7mub-IwjLzGKB95A1hSg6tA8X29-I6BaX3-abI', 'token_type': 'Bearer', 'not-before-policy': 0, 'session_state': 'a17c1d77-c923-4e7e-9fe8-356e54973429', 'scope': 'profile email'}
```

but the output of #2 print is:

```
CREATE USER  <Response [401]> b'{"error":"HTTP 401 Unauthorized"}' {"error":"HTTP 401 Unauthorized"}
```

I tried also another payload to request the token, you can see it commented, it's return me an access_token (but not the refresh token) but still the same error when i try to create a new user